# Append article and section using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am using AJAX to display posts, I'm trying to take each property from a JSON object I return and create an `<article>` from the title then a subsequent `<section>` from the content. I can add the title to the page fine, however I'm unsure on how to add the section in the same for loop.

JS:

```
function loadBlog(xhr) {
    var mainText = document.querySelector('.main-text');
    var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    for(var i = 0; i < countObject(result); i++) {
        var title =  document.createElement('article').appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].title));
        var data = document.createElement('section').appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].content));
        var output = mainText.appendChild(title)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you need to append `data` to `title` first, but you should do it in a loop. I'll write up some code for you.

Comment: Actually, no I won't it's too simple. If you only have one content that matches each title, just add a single line `title = title.appendChild(data);` I personally would use a templating framework like Underscore templates though, http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, i get `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.` when using your code.

Comment: Yes, I think that is because `appendChild` returns a reference to the appended node instead of the parent element (docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.appendChild) Get rid of `title =`, just make it `title.appendChild(data);` I am unfamiliar with doing this through pure javascript.

Comment: nope still same error, hmm :/

Comment: Can you give us an example of expected produced html ?

Comment: One more try, it could be because of when you assign title, you are getting the result of `appendChild`, which is the text node. Try this: `var title =  document.createElement('article');` Then on separate lines: `title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].title));` and `var data = document.createElement('section');`, `data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].content));`, and finally `title.appendChild(data);`

Comment: Test out Norguard's answer, it is the same idea, but better looking code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `.appendChild` returns the child (which is a TextNode), instead of the parent, which is an Article.

```
var article = document.createElement("article"),
    title   = document.createElement("h1"),
    titleText = document.createTextNode(result[i].title),
    content = document.createElement("section"),
    contentText = document.createTextNode(result[i].content);

title.appendChild(titleText);
content.appendChild(contentText);
article.appendChild(title);
article.appendChild(content);
```

If you *really* want to chain them together, then you can do something like:

```
var article = document.createElement("article")
                  .appendChild(document.createElement("h1"))
                      .appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].title))
                  .parentNode.parentNode // out of the textNode, out of the H1
                  .appendChild(document.createElement("section"))
                      .appendChild(document.createTextNode(result[i].content))
                  // now you have to go up, out of the article-text
                  // and up out of the Section, to get back to the Article
                  .parentNode.parentNode;
```

Comment: ...which console are you using?  `.createElement` creates elements, and `.createTextNode` creates text nodes, this particular code (aside from `<article>` and `<section>` being invalid, should go back to IE4 or earlier.

Comment: ...styling?  ...inserting HTML from JSON, without using a library to handle it for you, is typically a *very* bad idea.  If you really, really want to go down that road, then you need to save references to a title-element (should not be just pasted in the article), and the content element...  ...as in, save them as vars and append later.  Then you can say `titleEl.innerHTML = result.title; contentEl.innerHTML = result.content;`.  But again, really not a good idea if this is for anything more than you learning and seeing how JS interacts with the DOM... If you want this public, us a library.